# Field 'id' expected a number but got '' in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

blog_id is not get. help me to solve this ---
**models.py**

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    body = models.TextField()
    last_updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author_instance = models.ForeignKey(AuthorInstance, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    status_draft = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    status_publish = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(UserInstance, related_name='like', default=None, blank=True)
    like_count = models.BigIntegerField(default='0')

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

**`views.py`**

```
 def like_post(request):
    post = get_object_or_404(Blog, id=request.POST.get('blog_id'))
```

how to solve????

Comment: Are you sure the 'blog_id' element is present in your POST request ?

Comment: please show us urls.py

Comment: path('login_author/', views.login_author, name="login_author"),
    path('author_page/', views.author_page, name='author_page'),
    path('admin_page/', views.admin_page, name='admin_page'),
    path('create_blog/', views.create_blog, name="create_blog"),
    path('blog_page/<int:blog_id>', views.one_page, name="one_page"),
    path('logout/', views.logout, name="logout"),
    path('like/<int:pk>', views.like_blog, name="like_blog"),
    path('edit_blog/<int:blog_id>', views.editblog, name="editblog"),
    path('post_detail/<int:blog_id>', views.post_detail, name="post_detail"),
]

Answer (score 0):

views should be like

```
def like_post(request,id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Blog, id=request.POST.get('blog_id'))
```